# SQL Server and date + 1 result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In case of the SQL Server. Say, if I have a table with [myDate] column that is of the type datetime, what would adding 1 to it mean in the following context?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [myTable] 
 WHERE [myDate] + 1 > @someDate
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Please be very careful with using shorthand notation like this instead of proper DATEADD() statements. While admittedly harder to type, DATEADD() is much easier to read, but more importantly, it will break with the new date/time types in SQL Server 2008. Try adding 1 to a DATE for example: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 - Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It adds one day (exactly 24 hours)

However, your query is more correct this way. The function or processing on the column usually invalidates index usage if there is one of that column

```
WHERE [myDate] > @someDate - 1
```

OR

```
WHERE [myDate] > DATEADD(day, -1, @someDate)
```

Comment: @marc_s: yes, relies on the internal storage as whole days since 1900 + fractional time. No different to the DATEADD/DATEDIFF trick to remove time where we use 0 rather than 01 Jan 1900

Comment: That's an interesting point about invalidating the index usage. I the average developer doesn't think about that when writing a query.

Comment: @Adam Porad: number 2 in top 10 SQL mistakes: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Comment: .. "usually" invalidates index usage ... ??   it ALWAYS invalidates index usage

Comment: @gbn: great link! Thanks. Almost as good as Brent Ozar's [Top Ten Developer's Mistakes That Won't Scale](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/the-top-10-developer-mistakes-that-wont-scale/) :-)

Comment: @Charles Bretana: not always in later versions. Was an answer/comment here about it.. will see if I can find it

Comment: Very nice info about SQL and indexes. THANK YOU for sharing! So what else invalidates index usage. Is there an official document that details it? That would be very helpful!

Comment: @ahmd0: it's safe to assume anywhere you don't use a column directly but have some processing on it

Answer (score 4):

Use the **`DATEADD`** function (see [MSDN docs for DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for details):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.myTable
 WHERE DATEADD(D, 1, myDate) > @someDate
```

`DATEADD` allows you to add any of the usual date parts (day, month, year) and also time parts (hours, minutes, seconds) etc.

Comment: So, is it the same as adding a day? Will wring + 1 be actually faster?

Comment: @ahmd0: I don't think one or the other will be faster or slower in a any significant way - or do you **really** need to have sub-nanosecond optimizations?!?!??

Comment: @ahmd0: both methods will be slower than having `someDate - 1`

Answer (score 2):

A DATETIME can be expressed as a decimal value.  The integer part represents the date while the decimal value represents the time.

So [DATETIME] + 1 means 'same time the next day'.

DateAdd is safer, as it assumes nothing about the underlying implementation.

Comment: Oh, so adding 1.5 will add one day and 12 hours? And regarding DateAdd, I'm looking for the fastest implementation.

Comment: @ahmd0: I wouldn't rely **too much** on internals of anything - use the documented, supported API - the DATEADD function - much safer! Internals might suddenly change...

Comment: Yup. If you need to eek out every last bit of performance, feel free. But document it so that you (or the next guy who maintains it) doesn't have to come back and ask the same question! ;-)

Comment: DateAdd is extremely fast... see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It will add one day.  This takes advantedge of the fact that SQL Server stores dates as two integers, one representing the number of days since day "0" - (1 jan 1900), and the second one which represents the number of ticks (about 3.33 ms) since midnight (for the time) *.

To make your queries use an index... use this formula on the input filtering parameters first, or on the "other" side of the equal sign from the tables date time field, so that the query optimizer does not have to run the calculation on every datetime field in the table to determine which rows satisfy the filter predicate. This makes your search argument "SARG-able" (Search ARGument)

```
 Where MyDateTimeColumn > DateAdd(day,       
         datediff(day,0, @MydateParameter), 0)    -- SARG-able
```

rather than

```
 Where DateAdd(day, datediff(day,0,       
   MyDateTimeColumn ), 0) > MydateParameter -- Not SARG-able •
```

In your case, this means use

```
   Select *
   FROM [myTable]  
   WHERE [myDate]  > @someDate - 1
```

rather than

```
   Select *
   FROM [myTable]  
   WHERE [myDate] + 1  > @someDate
```

NOTE. Internally, the second integer (the time part) stores ticks. In a day there are 24 x 60 X 60 X 300 = 25,920,000 ticks (serendipitously just below the max value a 32 bit integer can hold). However, you do not need to worry about this when arithmetically modifying a datetime... When adding or subtracting values from datetimes you can treat the value as a fraction as though it was exactly equal to the fractional portion of a day, as though the complete datetime value was a floating point number consisting of an integer portion representing the date and the fractional portion representing the time). i.e.,

```
  Declare @Dt DateTime Set @Dt = getdate()
  Set @Dt = @Dt + 1.0/24 -- Adds one hour
  Select @Dt
  Set @Dt = @Dt - .25 -- Moves back 6 hours
  Select @Dt
```

Answer (score 0):

It should add 1 day (24 hours) to the date, adding 0.5 will had half a day (12 hours) and adding 2 will add days (48 hours), etc. But @Barry makes a good point in his comment. You could try it and find out.

If you want to add other minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc. You should use the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function that is built-in to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a number to a DATE type does not work.

This works:

```
SELECT CAST('2014-11-21 14:30' AS DATETIME) + 1
```

This does not:

```
SELECT CAST('2014-11-21 14:30' AS DATE) + 1
```

This can be an issue when updating database drivers that may map a date type to DATETIME (because that's all there was in SQL2005), but change to use DATE.