# Is there any way of showcasing monthly date wise total in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Is there any way to do this in SQL as right now i have to run same query 30 times by using union all 30 times for monthly total which takes lot of execution time.
If possible then it will be huge help.

Example:sum of item quantity on each day of given month

1 July- I want total of item qty from day transaction started , 2 nd July-I want total of item qty from day transaction started + 1st July qty , 3 rd July -total of item qty from day transaction started + 1st July qty+ 2 nd July qty
Thanks in advance

```
Declare @DateTo DateTime
Set @DateTo='2018-07-19'

Select @DateTo DateTo, [Item No_], sum(Quantity) from 
[Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Posting Date]<=@DateTo and [Item No_]='H1023038'
Group by [Item No_]

union all
Select @DateTo+1 DateTo, [Item No_], sum(Quantity) from 
[Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Posting Date]<=@DateTo+1 and [Item No_]='H1023038'
Group by [Item No_]

union all
Select @DateTo+2 DateTo, [Item No_], sum(Quantity) from 
[Snowman Logistics Limited$Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Posting Date]<=@DateTo+2 and [Item No_]='H1023038'
Group by [Item No_]
```

Result below

```
DateTo                  Item No_               (Quantity)
2018-07-19 00:00:00.000 H1023038    0.00000000000000000000
2018-07-20 00:00:00.000 H1023038    20100.00000000000000000000
2018-07-21 00:00:00.000 H1023038    12500.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: you could group by the (month portion of) the date. e.g. group by month(Posting_Date), Item_no I think.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use whitespace when writing SQL. It not only helps you read your SQL more easily, but others as well.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, this asks for LEAD/LAG. you want to include the previous day's sum in each subsequent figure? what about different number of days per month?

Comment: Not sure what `@DateTo+1 DateTo` means? Either way, if you're performing date arithmetic use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`. `{A datetime} + {integer}` works, when `{A Datetime}` is the `datetime` datatype, but it won't if you ever use `date`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: adding/subtracting integers is a bit of an Oracle idiom, but should be [perfectly valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6719767/1132334) in tsql as well

Comment: @dlatikay but it isn't. `DECLARE @d date = GETDATE(); SET @d = @D + 1;`, `DECLARE @dt datetime2(0) = GETDATE(); SET @dt = @dt + 1;` and `DECLARE @dto datetimeoffset = GETDATE(); SET @dto = @dto + 1;` will all fail with the error `Operand type clash: {datatype} is incompatible with int`.

Comment: The documentation for [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), even states that `datetime` shouldn't be used in new work: *"Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable."*, which also means that in new work `{datetime2} + {int}` will fail.

Comment: right. one of the reasons why it is so hard to transition large projects from datetime to datetime2 even in 2018: it breaks legacy code and I'm still not sure if the alleged indexability advantage of the arithmetic method is compensated for in all sql server versions that support datetime2.

Comment: is there any way to get it done in query instead of querying 30 time using union

Comment: sure. for example with the [LAG window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). One of their samples in that article even comes close to what you need to achieve. But we must clarify how you define the months first: do all have 30 days, what about february, do you have a calendar lookup table maybe? you example does it until the 19th of a month. does that mean it should look 30 days back from there? or include just july from there?

Comment: Example: sum of item quantity on each day of given month

Comment: what you could do is make a date table, then join the queried table to your date table and use just one of your queries.  You will select just the days of the month you are interested in from the date table

Comment: I see you have tagged this with both 2008 and 2016. The best solution will vary depending which one you are actually using.

Comment: dear sir , i want complete month data of that item in one time is that possible with that.

Comment: Correcting  :sum of item quantity  on each day of given month For example: 1 July- I want total of item qty from day transaction started , 2 nd July-I want total of item qty from day transaction started + 1st July qty , 3 rd July -total of item qty from day transaction started  + 1st July qty+ 2 nd July qty

Comment: THat's not the same as a "monthly total". That implies you want one figure for the whole month, not a single day. You actually want a "daily total" in which case you can just group by the (date portion of) the posting date. Of course any days on which nothing was posted will not have a row, but you can safely assume the total on those days is 0.

Comment: in my understanding this is still a running total. subsequent days cleary include everything before 2018-07-19 (which makes me wonder what range `Item Ledger Entry` contains?)

Comment: @Adyson Correct